# Chaining Promises in Vue not working as expected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise

I’m sure im missing something but as I can’t figure it out thought I might check here.

So in short I want to do this in Vue (https://codesandbox.io/s/6zlmkm61m3)

```js
function p1() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('p1')
    resolve()
  })
}

function p2() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('p2')
    reject('p2')
  })
}

p1()
  .then(p2)
  .catch((error) => {

    console.log(error)
  })
```

However if I extract this to Vue it gives me `Uncaught (in promise)`

https://codesandbox.io/s/mq2343y6p8

So i'm not sure if this is due to Vue and how i'm calling the methods but any help would be appreciated.

Vue code:

```
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Hello,
    World
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {
    checkPromise() {
      this.$refs.promiseOne
        .p1()
        .then(this.$refs.promiseTwo.p2())
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: You should handle your rejection in ```p2```. So, ```p2.catch((error)=>{})``` will resolve this message

Comment: thanks, i should have put that in the original question that i know how to fix the error it was more as to why i was getting that error, the accepted answer was what i was missing...doh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problematic line in question is:

```
.then(this.$refs.promiseTwo.p2())
```

where `this.$refs.promiseTwo.p2` refers to the function that returns the Promise. But you're not *passing* the function as a parameter to `then` (which is what should be done normally, as in your live snippet here on SO) - you're *calling* the function and then passing its result to the `.then`.

Change to

```
.then(this.$refs.promiseTwo.p2)
```

and it should work as expected.

Your code on codesandbox, translated into a live snippet here, looks like

```js
function p1() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('p1')
    resolve()
  })
}

function p2() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('p2')
    reject('p2')
  })
}

p1()
  .then(p2()) // <------- problem: p2 is invoked, not passed
  .catch((error) => {

    console.log(error)
  })
```

(open your *actual browser*'s console on this page to see `Uncaught (in promise) p2`)

Comment: That did the trick, i'll accept it as soon as SO let's me. It's so obvious now...sigh thanks a lot i was wondering what the heck i did wrong.